# Datepicker - How to set default date to next available date and not "today"?

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I am using datepicker for my site. I have chosen some days to not accept orders. When I have disabled a day, and it is actually that day, the default date is chosen as that day even though I have it as disallowed.

Let me explain:

- 17th March - is disabled date so users cannot select that date
- User goes to the site on 17th March and the text field shows the default date which is 17th March
- When the user submits the form without selecting a new date - 17th March gets passed through as the date as it was default.

What I would like to happen is that the default date is set to the next available date which in my example would be 18th March..

Is there a way to set the default date to the next available date after the disabled date?

Thanks in advance.

My JS code so far is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#input_1_16").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: nationalDays, minDate: 0, maxDate: "+4m"})   

natDays = [
    [1, 26], 
    [2, 6],
    [3, 15,17],
    [4, 27], 
    [5, 15,25], 
    [6, 6],
    [7,19], 
    [8,27], 
    [9,],
    [10,], 
    [11,], 
    [12,23,24,25,30,31]
];

function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
      if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
          && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
        return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
      }
    }
  return [true, ''];
}

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My buddy was able to answer this for me: The code is as follows as there is a working example of it here http://jsfiddle.net/NHdEX/8/

```
natDays = [
      [1,26], 
    [2,6],
    [3,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31],
      [4,27], 
      [5,15,25], 
      [6,6],
      [7,19], 
      [8,27], 
      [9],
      [10], 
      [11], 
      [12,23,24,25,30,31]
];

function getMinDate() {
    var now = new Date();

    var monthnumber = now.getMonth();
    var monthday = now.getDate();
    var year = now.getFullYear();

    //check if today is a holiday. 
    //by default do not skip any dates, allow user to select today. 
    var dayOffset = 0; 

    var date; 
    var currentDay = monthday; 

    var currentMonth = monthnumber; 
    for(var i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++){
        date = natDays[i]; 
        //check month
        if(date[0] == currentMonth+1){
            for(var j=1;j<date.length;j++){
                currentDay == 0; 
                while(date[j] == currentDay){
                    dayOffset++; 
                    currentDay++;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //calculate the new date. 
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + dayOffset);

    return (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getDate() + '/' + now.getFullYear();
}

function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
      if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
          && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
        return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
      }
    }
  return [true, ''];
}


$("#input_1_16").val(getMinDate());
$("#input_1_16").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: nationalDays, minDate: getMinDate(), maxDate: "+4m"});
```

​

Comment: Are you sure that's the solution? On the jsfiddle, I can only navigate to July, and nothing is selectable past the 16th

Comment: I have max date set to +4M in that example, just remove max date

Comment: Ah, nice! Didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Getting the first good day
var default = new Date();
while(nationalDays(default)[0]){
   default = new Date().setDate(default.getDate()+1);
}

// Creating by giving the first good day as default
$("#input_1_16").datepicker({defaultDate: default beforeShowDay: nationalDays, minDate: 0, maxDate: "+4m"});
```

Comment: Hi, i tried inserting your code in mine, but did not seem to work. Are you suggesting that I basically copy your code and paste it over my line `$("#input_1_16"..............."+4m"})` ??? If you have the full code, including mine I should be using that would be awesome. thanks